# soulutf8's highlight fails with accents in moving argument (section)

Tags: sectioning, soul

The following MCE fails to compile (at second run) with error:

> ! Argument of \@firstofone has an extra }.
>    
>                   \par 
>   l.3 ...{\numberline {3}\texthl {Caf\IeC {\'e}}}{1}

as soon as the line `\section{\hl{Café}}` is commented out (even if `\hl` is preceded by `\protect`).

How could I make it work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{\hl{Caf\'e}}
\section[\hl{Caf\'e}]{\hl{Café}}
% \section{\hl{Café}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register `\IeC` to `soul`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soulutf8}

\soulregister\IeC{1}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{\hl{Caf\'e}}
\section[\hl{Caf\'e}]{\hl{Café}}
\section{\hl{Café}}

\end{document}
```

In my opinion `soulutf8` should do it to begin with.

Comment: I'll draw Heiko's attention.